# Split up hash into attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, split, mongoid

Mongoid is returning the following:

```
{"name"=>"First"} {"name"=>"Second"} #<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:0x007fda65760420>
```

How can I split this into the following?

'First'

'Second'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterate over the context and push the data to an array or a hash? http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo#each-instance_method